# PDO mysql query problem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I am building a login/signup site with PDO just for fun on wamp...

I am currently building a users online page, when a user accesses any member page it updates a column called online in my mysql table with a unix timestamp.

On the users online page I am trying to find and show all the users who qualify for being online which is being active in the last ten minutes. So far I have this...

```
$online_users = time() - 600;

$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE online > ?");
$q -> execute(array($online_users));
$online_user = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($q) {
echo '<p> ' . $player_details['username'] . ' is online.</p>';
}
```

The problem I am having is that it is looping over and over again, I would like it to loop through the table once, and display all the users who the mysql query only once...

I am new to PDO and am self learning, so if it is something really daft please excuse me!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: BTW, aren't you getting a bunch of `notice`'s?

Comment: No I just got an infinite page of the results.

Comment: You are storing info in `$online_user` and reading it from `$player_details`. PHP can warn you about it and help you save time and headaches: have a look at [error_reporting()](http://php.net/error_reporting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read once first and loop forever afterwards:

```
$online_user = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($q) {
```

Instead, read on every loop iteration:

```
while ($online_user = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Additionally, don't forget to `htmlspecialchars()` accordingly.

Comment: htmlspecialchars?? I thought PDO checked all this for me?? could you elaborate please, and thanks for your quick and helpful answer will accept as soon as I can :)

Comment: PDO has no clue about what your data contains and what you are going to use it for. When a programming language makes assumptions about it, you end up with terrible mistakes like [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php).

Answer (score 0):

Also you use the following code:

```
$online_users = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($online_users as $user) {
    echo '<p> ' . $user['username'] . ' is online.</p>';
}
```

Comment: is there any difference to using the your answer or the one above yours??

Comment: Principally no. You can try to check speed of each answer and select the best.

Comment: @carlgcoder: This stores the complete result set into a PHP variable. If you only need to use your data once, as in your question, it doesn't really matter... unless you are retrieving 10,000 rows.